# How to fix disappearing All my books in iBook

Tags: macos, books

When I open some book it is show me an alert message "This book can't be opened" and then all books disappear.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Could you take a stab at searching for some article on how to do basic troubleshooting on OS X and edit what step you need help with into the question. This is a little too vague/broad for people to do much but guess what you have tried or even what your skill level is.

Comment: Also, this janky set of steps might help if you don't have a backup and can't wait for AppleCare to get you a better answer... https://discussions.apple.com/message/29021775#29021775